# Is there any way to live stream processed video on google colab?

Tags: computer-vision, video-streaming, google-colaboratory, object-detection, opencv, python

Currently, I am trying to implement real-time object detection on video using yolov3 on google colab platform. I am unable to stream processed video in colab itself and I didn't get any exact solution for it. The normal workaround usually provided was, Save the processed video and then download it to identify detected objects in video.

P.S This may sound a silly question but I haven't found a proper solution for this.